# How to realise and interprete the interaction term in Cox regression model like this?

Tags: interaction, cox-model

There are two covariates: smoking history(yes or no) and gender(male or female), and the outcome is OA. The author of a paper constructed a Cox regression model with an outcome including this: smoking percentage with sex as a subgroup, and receive hazard ratio of each subgroup.

[image: Here is the subgroup and related HR]

[The original paper.](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32385660/)

So, the questions are:

1. Can the HR be interpreted like this: in males, the HR of having OA in smokers vs. non-smokers is 1.29?
2. How can I get the interaction variable of smoking history and gender like that?

Comment: Have you built the model OA~gender*smoking ? It would help if you were giving more precision about the structure of your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Actually, the question comes from a [paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32385660/) I read. The data structure I speculate is every observation stands for a subject, and columns include gender(male or female) and smoking history(ever-smoker or non-smoker). The regression OA ~ gender * smoking will not yield the results shown in the picture since there is separate HR for male smokers and female smokers, which can not be reached by multiplication. Is the regression supposed to be like this: OA ~ smoking history, data = df[df$gender = 'male']?